# Few complete subspaces of the space $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, complete-spaces

$$X\subset \mathbb R^n$$ a subspace  with  Euclidean  metric on $\mathbb R^n.$ Then the $X$ that is complete is **:**

$A.X=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z\subset \mathbb R\times \mathbb R.$

$B.X=\mathbb Q\times \mathbb R\subset \mathbb R\times \mathbb R.$

$C.X=(-\pi,\pi)\cap\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R.$

$D.X=[-\pi,\pi]\cap \mathbb Q^c\subset \mathbb R.$

For $A$ , I guess  the  only  ***Cauchy sequences***  will  be the ***constant*** sequences so  that will be  **complete.**

For $B$ , since $\mathbb Q$ is  not complete  in  $\mathbb R$ , a  ***Cauchy*** sequence can be found that  will not converge in the given $X.$ So ***not complete.***

For $C$ , a Cauchy sequence in the $X$ can be found that converges to $\pi$  or  $-\pi$,thus not converging inside $X.$ So , ***not complete.***

For $D$ , if $x\in [\pi,-\pi]\cap \mathbb Q$ , then I think we  could find a **Cauchy**  sequence in $X$ that converges to $x$  and thus  $X$ in $D$ is also ***not complete.***

Did I make any  mistakes  here $?$

Comment: Looks good. You just need to prove all the claims you made

Comment: The Cauchy sequences in A are the ones that are _eventually_ constant. Important detail, but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @Arthur : So my answer  is  correct  , except for that , *minor  but very important * detail $?$

Comment: @AlexG. : So the result is correct $?$

Comment: I would personally supply a specific sequence in each non-complete case instead of just saying that one can be found, and you actually need to prove that claim for A (take $\epsilon =0.5$, and it should work out nicely). But apart from that, yes, it looks good.

Comment: @Arthur : Yes , of course . I'm actually  now  trying to  write  down sequences   in  my  copy that match the criteria of the question.

Comment: For  B, the projection of $R^2$ onto a co-ordinate maps open sets of $R^2$ onto open sets of $R$. So if $A$ is a non-closed subset of  $R$ then $A\times R$ is not closed in $R^2$, otherwise the projection of its complement would be open in $R$.